# How to use GPT-2 for topic modelling?

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling, bert-language-model, gpt-2

I want to generate topics and subtopics from a corpus. It would be great if someone could share the python code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest way to do this would be by using the hugginface library. They already have scripts for generating text from several generative models, including gpt-2.The script you're looking for is `run_generation.py`.You can provide prompts of varying lengths and it can generate text using them.